# Run curses based python script on start up [raspbian stretch]

Tags: python, boot, raspbian-stretch

I'm trying to auto start a curses based python script on startup of my RPi 3+ (running on raspbian stretch)

What I did so far.

I've got a python script `demo1.py`,

```
import curses                                                                
from curses import panel                                                     

class Menu(object):                                                          

    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):                                    
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(0,0)                                  
        self.window.keypad(1)                                                
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)                            
        self.panel.hide()                                                    
        panel.update_panels()                                                

        self.position = 0                                                    
        self.items = items                                                   
        self.items.append(('exit','exit'))                                   

    def navigate(self, n):                                                   
        self.position += n                                                   
        if self.position < 0:                                                
            self.position = 0                                                
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):                               
            self.position = len(self.items)-1                                

    def display(self):                                                       
        self.panel.top()                                                     
        self.panel.show()                                                    
        self.window.clear()                                                  

        while True:                                                          
            self.window.refresh()                                            
            curses.doupdate()                                                
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):                        
                if index == self.position:                                   
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE                                  
                else:                                                        
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL                                   

                msg = '%d. %s' % (index, item[0])                            
                self.window.addstr(1+index, 1, msg, mode)                    

            key = self.window.getch()                                        

            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:                         
                if self.position == len(self.items)-1:                       
                    break                                                    
                else:                                                        
                    self.items[self.position][1]()                           

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:                                       
                self.navigate(-1)                                            

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:                                     
                self.navigate(1)                                             

        self.window.clear()                                                  
        self.panel.hide()                                                    
        panel.update_panels()                                                
        curses.doupdate()

class MyApp(object):                                                         

    def __init__(self, stdscreen):                                           
        self.screen = stdscreen                                              
        curses.curs_set(0)                                                   

        submenu_items = [                                                    
                ('beep', curses.beep),                                       
                ('flash', curses.flash)                                      
                ]                                                            
        submenu = Menu(submenu_items, self.screen)                           

        main_menu_items = [                                                  
                ('beep', curses.beep),                                       
                ('flash', curses.flash),                                     
                ('submenu', submenu.display)                                 
                ]                                                            
        main_menu = Menu(main_menu_items, self.screen)                       
        main_menu.display()                                                  

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                       
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)
```

created another script `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/demo1.py
```

I made the `script.sh` executable for all users and placed the absolute path to it in end of `rc.local`, didn't work.

I also tried `.bashrc` for pi user and made auto login in `raspi-config` that also didn't do any good.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it. Just use a systemd Unit file. Does `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/demo1.py` runs from the command line?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/demo1.py` runs fine.

Comment: OK, then create a systemd Unit file with the same environment setting for `User=pi`. You will find many examples here on this site.

Comment: @Ingo I tried it but it didn't work Can you please explain the content of the `.service` script

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the systemd Unit file to it that you have tried, so we can correct it.